# Remove element from array and move it to another

Tags: javascript

I have to randomly generate quiz and the answers are 3 random names from which 1 is correct, I've got the randomizing and shuffle done, but I gotta get the displayed element out of the array when it has shown up so it doesn't get randomized and picked again when I click next and when I click next it shows the next randomized thing, but for now it doesn't switch it. Anyone can help?

```js
var receivedArray   = JSON.parse(0: {nameIMGTOP: "-5", nameIMGTOPafter: "-10", nameIMGLEFT: "18", nameIMGLEFTafter: "22", nameTOP: "-3"}
1: {nameIMGTOP: "13", nameIMGTOPafter: "11", nameIMGLEFT: "27", nameIMGLEFTafter: "11", nameTOP: "32"}
2: {nameIMGTOP: "-6", nameIMGTOPafter: "", nameIMGLEFT: "36", nameIMGLEFTafter: "", nameTOP: "-3"}
3: {nameIMGTOP: "16", nameIMGTOPafter: "", nameIMGLEFT: "55", nameIMGLEFTafter: "", nameTOP: "18"}
4: {nameIMGTOP: "13", nameIMGTOPafter: "", nameIMGLEFT: "73", nameIMGLEFTafter: "", nameTOP: "37"});
    console.log(receivedArray);
    const StartElements = receivedArray;
    const correctAnswer = StartElements.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * StartElements.length), 1)[0];
    const guess1        = StartElements.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * StartElements.length), 1)[0];
    const guess2        = StartElements.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * StartElements.length), 1)[0];
    //array with few elements and variables for randomizing different things from the array
    
    function move() {
        array = new Array([]);
          while(correctAnswer !== 1){
            correctAnswer.splice();
            array.push(correctAnswer);
            console.log(array);
          }
    }
    //I've tried many different things and I can't get it down
    
    //Everything displays in Jquery made HTML
    $("#test-div").append(
            "<div class=\"row\">\n"+
            "<div class=\"col-6\">\n" +
            "<div class=\"ImageDiv\">" +
            "<img id=\"testImage\" src=\"\" alt='...' align=\"middle\"/>\n" +
            "</div>" +
            "</div>\n" +
            "<h4 class=\"Guess\" id=\"Guess\">ATMINI JŪRNIEKU MEZGLA NOSAUKUMU</h4>\n"+
            "<p id=\"description\"></p>"+
            "<div class=\"col-6 shuffle\">\n" +
            "<div class=\"btn guesses\" >"+correctAnswer.nameLV+"</div><br>"+
            "<div class=\"btn guesses\" >"+guess1.nameLV+"</div><br>"+
            "<div class=\"btn guesses\" >"+guess2.nameLV+"</div><br>"+
            "</div>\n" +
            "</div>\n"
            );
```

Comment: It's quite hard to see what you're trying to do, you should boil it down to a much simpler case. If you do that you'll probably work it out yourself, but even if you can't it will make it much easier for others to help.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comment, it's quite hard to work out what you want to do but if it's simply a matter of 'removing a particular item' then using [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) is a nice and simple way to do it:

```js
const startArray = [{0: 'item 0'}, {1: 'item 1'}, {2: 'item 2'}, {3: 'item 3'}]

const elementToRemove = startArray[1] // or whichever item you want

const newArray = startArray.filter(item => item !== elementToRemove)

console.log(newArray)

// =>  [{0: 'item 0'}, {2: 'item 2'}, {2: 'item 3'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

did you try to use [Array.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) method ?

```js
const startArray = 
      [ { 0: 'item 0'} 
      , { 1: 'item 1'} 
      , { 2: 'item 2'} 
      , { 2: 'item 3'} 
      ] 
      
//  remove item = 2
 startArray.splice(2,1)

console.log( startArray )
```